# Active class not retained on the selected list item in the bootstrap nav bar in mvc3 after new page opens

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0 to create a navbar in my MVC3 application.
Also I am using jquery-1.11.1.js.

The problem I am facing is that my navbar is created properly and it's responsive too, but the "active" class is not retained on the selected navbar item once the new page loads.

What is happening is that when I click on the navbar item, selected item gets the "active" class but after the new page is loaded, selected item losses the "active" class and the "active" class goes to the first item in the nav list.

I am pasting the code below for reference:

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="navigationbar" 
             style="height:50px; background-color:black;">
            @Html.Partial("_navbar")
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            ......
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**_navbar.cshtml**:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default col-xs-10" role="navigation" 
     style="background-color: orange; border: 0px; border-radius: 0px; text-align: center;">
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-header navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarcollapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/ListOfEmployees">Employee List</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Register/Index">Registration</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Home/AddEmployee">Add Employee</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have included the below jquery code in the _navbar.cshtml:-

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function () {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery fires on click, then the page reloads. Try running that on page load instead.

Comment: @DavidG - Do you mean inside document.ready(). If I am doing that, than the default item also loose the "active" class and my above posted issue remains as is.

Comment: You won't be able to run the same js code on page load because the click event won't be preserved when the page reloads.  When the page loads, you'll have to tell where it's been routed to, and then apply the active class based on that.  Also, that way users who go directly to a url without clicking will have the same experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to determine that information when the page loads and dynamically add the `.active` class to the applicable menu item.  You can do that by using the routing information exposed by `html.ViewContext.RouteData` and an extension method that checks to see if it matches.

Update your `_navbar.cshtml` like this:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class='@Html.IsActive("Home", "Index")'>
            <a href="/Home/Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class='@Html.IsActive("Home", "ListOfEmployees")'>
            <a href="/Home/ListOfEmployees">Employee List</a>
        </li>
        <li class='@Html.IsActive("Register", "Index")'>
            <a href="/Register/Index">Registration</a>
        </li>
        <li class='@Html.IsActive("Home", "AddEmployee")'>
            <a href="/Home/AddEmployee">Add Employee</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then add the extension method `IsActive`:

```cs
public static class Utilities
{
    public static string IsActive(this HtmlHelper html, 
                                  string control,
                                  string action)
    {
        var routeData = html.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var routeAction = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
        var routeControl = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];

        // both must match
        var returnActive = control == routeControl &&
                           action == routeAction;

        return returnActive ? "active" : "";
    }
}
```

For more info, you can check an article I authored a while back about loading the [active class in bootstrap using ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codingeverything.com/2014/05/mvcbootstrapactivenavbar.html)